# Criar tabela dinâmica em JS para utilizar em HTML

Tags: javascript, tabela-html

Estou a tentar criar uma tabela em JavaScript para depois utilizá-la numa pagina, mas esta difícil de realizar

O objetivo é que a tabela represente um conjunto de camas de um hospital que irão ser geridas através da pagina HTML.

Como fazer isto?

Comment: Como assim? você quer gerar o código da tabela HTML através do Javascript?

Comment: Poste o código que já possui e seja mais específico em qual ponto é sua dúvida.

Comment: Boa tarde, minha resposta lhe ajudou? Por favor me informe se tiver alguma duvida ainda. se não e a resposta lhe foi útil, por favor marque a como "correta". Grato.

Comment: Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 8):

Para criar elementos dinamicos com JavaScript, você deve usar [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) e para adicionar a outro elemento html já existente, você deve usar [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Para criar uma tabela, você deve chamar algo como:

```
var novaTabela = document.createElement("table");
```

Para adicioná-la a um DIV existente como:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Você de fazer isto:

```
var novaTabela = document.createElement("table");
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(novaTabela);
```

A tabela geralmente necessita (é recomendável) de `<thead>` e `<tbody>` (as vezes pode-se usar `<tfoot>`, mas é opcional).

Para criar o `<thead>` e o `<tbody>` faça isto:

```
var tabela = document.createElement("table");
var cabecalho = document.createElement("thead");
var corpo = document.createElement("tbody");

tabela.appendChild(cabecalho);
tabela.appendChild(corpo);

document.getElementById("test").appendChild(tabela);
```

> Nota: Dentro do `<thead>`, use `<th>` ao invés de `<td>`

Leia sobre as tags:

- [table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html)
- [tbody](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html)
- [thead](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/thead.html)
- [th](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/th.html)
- [td](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html)

### Usando o `innerHTML`

Alguns vão criticar, mas não mata ninguém usar o [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) as vezes, você pode tentar algo como:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = [
  '<table>',
  '<thead>',
  '<tr>',
  '<th>id</th>',
  '<th>col1</th>',
  '<th>col2</th>',
  '<th>col3</th>',
  '</tr>',
  '</thead>',
  '<tbody>',
  '<tr>',
  '<td>1</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '</tr>',
  '<tr>',
  '<td>2</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '</tr>',
  '<tr>',
  '<td>3</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '<td>data</td>',
  '</tr>',
  '</tbody>',
  '</table>'
].join("\n");
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
  width: 100%;
}
table th {
  background-color: #00f;
  color: #fff;
}
table td {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #0c0c0c;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Legal o código! Como posso fazer para retornar dados em JSON e criar as <td> dinamicamente?

Answer (score 5):

Criei essa função pra você, se quiser usa-la.

```js
function criarTabela(conteudo) {
  var tabela = document.createElement("table");
  var thead = document.createElement("thead");
  var tbody=document.createElement("tbody");
  var thd=function(i){return (i==0)?"th":"td";};
  for (var i=0;i<conteudo.length;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var o=0;o<conteudo[i].length;o++){
      var t = document.createElement(thd(i));
      var texto=document.createTextNode(conteudo[i][o]);
      t.appendChild(texto);
      tr.appendChild(t);
    }
    (i==0)?thead.appendChild(tr):tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tabela.appendChild(thead);
  tabela.appendChild(tbody);
  return tabela;
}
document.getElementById("tabela").appendChild(criarTabela([
  ["id", "nome",     "idade"],
  [1,    "matheus",  16],
  [2,    "cristian", 16],
  [3,    "pedro",    10],
  [4,    "henrique", 10]
]));
```

```html
<div id="tabela"></div>
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, Mateus obrigado pela colaboração, porém o objetivo da comunidade é apresentar "respostas" as questões, ou seja, a sua resposta deve ser uma "RESPOSTA" a pergunta e não um compartilhamento de código apenas. No [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) leia a parte que fala "Obtenha respostas para perguntas práticas e detalhadas" e depois leia http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sei que a pergunta é antiga. Mas não concordo com seu comentário. Existem muitas respostas por aqui que são apenas códigos, e nesse caso aqui, o Matheus apresentou um código funcional e de acordo com a pergunta.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Talvez você não entenda o proposito do site, vou lhe explicar, espero que não leve a mal. O proposito não é apenas dar código aqui no site, mas sim conhecimento, um código é legal, mas ele deve vir acompanhado de uma explicação, em nenhum momento eu disse que o código é ruim ou não funciona, ou seja eu não critiquei o código e sim a maneira que a resposta foi formulada. Isto que eu fiz se chama *critica construtiva*, note que na minha resposta abaixo eu expliquei as funções e citei fontes. Espero realmente que entenda isto como critica construtiva :)

Comment: @Matheus Cristin. Como posso fazer para retornar dados em JSON e criar as <td> dinamicamente?

Comment: So tenho a agradecer a postagem do senhor Mateus,pois foi a unica maneira que serviu para me ensinar como fazer, Postando um modelo funcional,curto e objetivo. Obrigado Mateus e a todos pelo espaco disponibilizado.