# Mostrar Tabuada em uma Tabela no HTML

Tags: html, css

Meu problema é o seguinte, só consigo exibir os resultados em um `alert`, como eu colocaria os valores dentro de uma tabela?

```
<title>-Calcular tabuada</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <
      function calcula_tabuada() {
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var n = form.numero.value;
        if (n.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
          var num = parseInt(n);
          var resultado = 0;
          tabuada = "";
          for (operando = 1; operando < 11; operando++) {
            resultado = num * operando;
            tabuada = tabuada + num + " * " + operando + " = " + resultado + "\n";
          }
          alert(tabuada);
        } else {
          alert("Digite um número inteiro válido.");
        }
      }
      //-->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="" method="get">
      <h3>Cálculo da tabuada utilizando for:</h3>
      <p>
        <label for="numero">Digite o número: </label>
        <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" value="" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="return calcula_tabuada();" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Então desenvolve a página e quando estiver com alguma dúvida específica, você posta aqui pra gente te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, sem problemas. Obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermeLima completando o que o bigown disse, não entenda mal, mas o Stack Overflow é um website de dúvidas e não de solicitações. Tente algo, em caso de dúvidas, poste seu código, sua tentativa, ai sim, muitas pessoas irão te ajudar :).

Comment: Sim, peço desculpas foi inocência de minha parte, atualizei minha duvida.

Comment: Eu não sou bom de manipular DOM mas acho que agora quem sabe consegue para responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não está em uma tabela mas imprime fora do alert:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>-Calcular tabuada</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   
   function calcula_tabuada() {
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var n = form.numero.value;
  if (n.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
    var num = parseInt(n);
    var resultado = 0;
    tabuada = "";

    for (operando = 1; operando < 11; operando++) {
   resultado = num * operando;
   tabuada = tabuada + num + " * " + operando + " = " + resultado +  "<br>\n";
    }
    document.write(tabuada);
  } else {
    alert("Digite um número inteiro válido.");
  }
   }
 
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <form id="form" action="" method="get">
   <h3>Cálculo da tabuada utilizando for:</h3>
   <p>
  <label for="numero">Digite o número: </label>
  <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" value="" />
   </p>
   <p>
  <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="return calcula_tabuada();" />
   </p>
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

O que você realmente quer esta procurando já foi demonstado aqui no stackoverflow: [Criar tabela dinâmica em JS para utilizar em HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49581/criar-tabela-din%C3%A2mica-em-js-para-utilizar-em-html). Espero ter ajudado!!

Answer (score 5):

Para realizar o que deseja, você precisa criar uma tabela em seu código **html** e em seu `for`, você adicionar os valores de acordo com a multiplicação.

Utilizando seu código como exemplo ficaria assim:

```css
#myTable{
display: none;
}

 td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <form id="form" action="" method="get">
      <h3>Cálculo da tabuada utilizando for:</h3>
      <p>
        <label for="numero">Digite o número: </label>
        <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" value="" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="return calcula_tabuada();" />
      </p>
    </form>
     
     <table id="myTable">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <td>Nº</td>
             <td>Multiplicador</td>
             <td>Resultado</td>
         </tr>
     </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
     </table>
    
     <script>
        function calcula_tabuada() {
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var n = form.numero.value;
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      
        if (n.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
          var num = parseInt(n);
          var resultado = 0;
          tabuada = "";
          for (operando = 10; operando > 0; operando--) {
            resultado = num * operando;
            var row = table.insertRow(1);//Seleciona a 1ª linha da tabela
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);//Insere td numero
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);//Insere td Multiplicador
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);//Insere td Resultado
            cell1.innerHTML = num;;//Valor do numero
            cell2.innerHTML = operando;;//Valor do Multiplicador
            cell3.innerHTML = resultado;;//Valor do Resultado
          }
          table.style.display = "block";//Torna a tabella visível
        } else {
          alert("Digite um número inteiro válido.");
        }
      }       
     </script>
```

**P.S.: O código está explicando o que faz em no próprio comentário do código.**

Comment: Caso não entenda alguma parte, avise que explico melhor.